# Obtain previous level of ordinal factor in R

Tags: r, categorical-data

I must be missing something in this question, because it looks simple and it has already been too much time on it.

Let's say we have a ordinal factor column in a dataframe. We want a new column by dropping or scaling up the original column by one level or category. What is the fastest way?

**Data**

```
col_string <- as.character(c(1:5))
col_factor <- factor(col_string, levels = as.character(c(1:8)), ordered = TRUE)
```

**Desired solution:**

```
col_solution <- c(8,1,2,3,4)
df <- cbind(col_string, col_factor, col_solution)
df
     col_string col_factor col_solution
[1,] "1"        "1"        "8"         
[2,] "2"        "2"        "1"         
[3,] "3"        "3"        "2"         
[4,] "4"        "4"        "3"         
[5,] "5"        "5"        "4"
```

How, in code, can i tell R to:

```
col_solution <- shift down one level of the element in col_factor
```

*edit for clarification:*

The `col_factor` column has 8 categories altough there are just representation of 5 of them. The categories are ordered as 1-2-3-4-5-6-7-8. If one element is on category 1 and we want to go down by one category, we would go to category 8.

Comment: did you mean the first element in `col_solution` is 5?

Comment: Sorry for the confusion. There are 8 posible categories.
The categories are orderes as 1-2-3-4-5-6-7-8

If to category 1 we shift down one category, we should go to category 8.

Comment: I think he wanted to access the -1st ("minus first") to 4th element. I think in Python it's easier than in R

Comment: Given that you already have a column with all the factors, this should work: col_solution = lag(levels(col_factor), default = max(levels(col_factor)))

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
function(myFactor,shift = -1){
    myFactor[] <- (as.numeric(myFactor)-1+shift)(length(levels(myFactor)))+1
    return(myFactor)
}
```

A bit of a pain to get your head around what the indexing is doing.

`((x-1) %% y) +1` Gives the remainder of x/y, but when the remainder is 0, it returns y.